# android services

Tags: android, service

I need to learn about making my own services and how to use these services.

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or anything which I can use? (I've already seen the [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com) site, but I am looking for something else...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a good start.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html